# IN operator doesn't return all record in the range

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I'm trying to return all the `matches` available within a range of `round`, each round can have different match. So I wrote this query:

```
SELECT m.id, m.round_id, m.gameweek
 FROM `match` m
 LEFT JOIN competition_rounds r ON m.round_id = r.id
 LEFT JOIN competition_seasons s ON r.season_id = s.id
 LEFT JOIN competition c ON c.id = s.competition_id
 WHERE 1 AND
 m.status = 5 AND
 m.round_id IN (488, 489, 490, 491) AND
 m.gameweek = (SELECT MAX(m2.gameweek)
                FROM `match` m2
                WHERE m2.round_id IN (488, 489, 490, 491))
```

now the problem is that the result return only the `matches` of the round with id 488, why the others round are ignored?
Thanks.

Comment: I guess round with id 488 has the max gameweek...

Comment: @jarlh mmm but my goal is to get for each round the max gameweek I should replace the IN with OR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT m.id, m.round_id, m.gameweek
 FROM `match` m
 LEFT JOIN competition_rounds r ON m.round_id = r.id
 LEFT JOIN competition_seasons s ON r.season_id = s.id
 LEFT JOIN competition c ON c.id = s.competition_id
 WHERE 1 AND
 m.status = 5 AND
 m.round_id IN (488, 489, 490, 491) AND
 m.gameweek = (SELECT MAX(m2.gameweek)
                FROM `match` m2
                WHERE m2.round_id = m.round_id)
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you may want:

```
SELECT m.id, m.round_id, m.gameweek
 FROM `match` m
 LEFT JOIN competition_rounds r ON m.round_id = r.id
 LEFT JOIN competition_seasons s ON r.season_id = s.id
 LEFT JOIN competition c ON c.id = s.competition_id
 WHERE 1 AND
 m.status = 5 AND
 m.round_id IN (488, 489, 490, 491) AND
 m.gameweek = (SELECT MAX(m2.gameweek)
                FROM `match` m2
                WHERE m2.round_id = m.round_id))
```

Answer (score 4):

I am guessing that this query is sufficient:

```
SELECT m.id, m.round_id, m.gameweek
FROM `match` m
WHERE 1 AND
      m.status = 5 AND
      m.round_id IN (488, 489, 490, 491) AND
      m.gameweek = (SELECT MAX(m2.gameweek)
                    FROM `match` m2
                    WHERE m2.round_id = m.round_id AND
                          m2.status = m.status
                   );
```

That is, you probably want to take the status into account as well.  And, you don't need the `JOIN`s unless you really want duplicates in the result.